# Reasonable method to store and read constant values

Tags: c#, xml, constants

So I have a xml structure with the following format:

```
< Smart>
  < Attribute>
    < id >1 </id >
    < name >name </ name>
    < description >description</ description >
  </ Attribute>
     .
     .
     .
</Smart>
```

I then need to get user input to produce a datatable, depending on what the user inputs different constants will be used. The ID is used to distinguish between the different constants. All these constants are predefined before startup. The following is my code to find desired constants and store them into a datatable

```
for ( int row = 0; row < rowcount; row++)
{
found = false;
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader ("Smart_Attributes.xml" );
textReader.ReadStartElement( "Smart" );
while (!found)
{
   textReader.ReadStartElement("Attribute" );
   DataId = Convert .ToByte(textReader.ReadElementString("id" ));

   if (DataId > id)
   {
      dataView[count][5] = "Unknown" ;
      dataView[count][7] = "Unknown" ;
      found = true ;
   }
   if (DataId == id)
   {
      dataView[count][5] = textReader.ReadElementString("name" );
      dataView[count][7] = textReader.ReadElementString("description" );
      found = true ;
   }
   else
   {
      textReader.ReadElementString("name" );
      textReader.ReadElementString("description" );
   }
   textReader.ReadEndElement(); //</Attribute>                            
}
count++;
}
}
```

this does work on getting the desired constants to be found fo their corresponding row. However it seems like a lot of work for not much gain. Could this potentially be done better using something like a dataset? any other suggestions would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of the `XmlTextReader` lies in its forward-only nature.  This allows you to read a very large file in just one sweep.  If your XML file is smaller, and you're happy to hold the whole structure in memory at any one time, you can use Linq2Xml, and read it into an `XDocument` class.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Smart_Attributes.xml");

var rows = doc.Descendants("Attribute").Where(e => e.Element("id").Value == id)
    .Select(e => new 
        {
            Name = e.Element("name").Value,
            Description = e.Element("description").Value
        });

// Load rows into your datatable
```